# Control panels for budget Linux webhosting?

Tags: hosting

We've got an old plesk installation today. Looking to replace the machine, and plesk/cPanel are pretty expensive. I've been looking at ispconfig, but it requires a lot of compiling in order to get quota and MySQL support for stuff like postfix etc.
This is far from optimal because that means any security patch for one of the services requires compiling, testing, deploying etc - as opposed to just yum update / apt-get upgrade and check that all services are running.

Are there ppl here with experiences of other options?

Need basic functionallity:

- web hosting, php/cgi etc
- ftp, imap, pop3, smtp, dns
- quota
- web control panel for customers
- does not have to be extremely pretty
- do not really care about support
- it can cost money, but not thousands of dollars like plesk :)
- Security patching will not require compilation of software or modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**VirtualMin** (www.virtualmin.com) has both a GPL and a paid version.
It is basically a webmin plugin and theme.

The really nice thing is that it uses your normal config files - so you can still edit them by hand and not mess up VirtualMin.

It is very easy to set up, and has a script to do so if you are running it on a fresh OS install.

Probably worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard positive things said about [DTC](http://www.gplhost.com/software-dtc.html) which is an open source solution and looks fairly feature complete, though I've not found time to try it myself yet.

[syscp](http://www.syscp.de/) may also be worth a look, which I actually found via DTC's "about/competitors" page, though again I've not tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

i think that http://www.directadmin.com/ is a cheap alternative to Cpanel/Plesk solution.